# Parametrized Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming, higher-order-functions, argument-dependent-lookup

My library has a several operations that naturally map to arithmetic and logic/boolean operators.  However, these operations require additional parameters besides `lhs` and `rhs`.

Here is a geometric example of what I mean demonstrated with [ClipperLib](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php#screenshots):
Let's say I want to create a polygon offset operator that takes a 2D polygon and an offset delta and performs polygon offsetting. This example is from ClipperLib:
[image]
Mathematically, this operation could be mapped to an `operator+` taking a polygon-type and a numeric-type.
However, the underlying *implementation* requires a few more parameters, e.g. mitering, precisions etc.

I want to combine the power, expressiveness and terseness of the math notation with the control and precision of the underlying implementation. I'd like to write:

```
// somehow materialize a properly parametrized operator+=()
poly += 10;
```

and have this do just what I want.

There are a few options for injecting these parameters into the binary overloaded operator, but each has its own drawbacks:

1. Set and use class-static/global (or thread local) parameters.
   But, using globals is bad for threading, discoverability, readability and cleanup.
2. Keep the extra parameters as members of the operator input types.
   This puts the type wrapping burden on the caller and may make the code more cumbersome. This is also unclear in terms of consistency which of the input types should have these params and what happens in case of conflicting or multiple param values from both.
   Also, if I want to perform the operation multiple times, I have to respecify the parameters over and over.

Can anyone suggest another approach that may work here?

One option that I am considering but am not yet sure how to make work is to have the overloaded operator as a template function in a separate namespace. The template would be parametrized over the required params (assume they are known at compile time), and once instantiated the operator is somehow pulled into the currently discoverable namespace where the ADL will correctly match it.
I am not sure if/how this can be pulled off.

Alternatively, use the same namespace hiding and revealing trick to add automatic type conversions for the operator input types so that they are automatically wrapped with types that provide the extra parameters.

Can this type of namespace hiding and exposing + ADL be done?

I guess this would be sorta like giving the operator a lambda-like behavior.

Comment: How about `poly += CArgs(10).decorateWithPrecision(0.15).decorateWithLineWidth(1.5);`?

Comment: `CArgs`? You mean create a custom wrapper as in option 2? Though this syntax is not bad, I wonder if the extra code could be moved into the operator instantiation somehow.

Comment: Yes option 2. You have 2 options. If args are constant, you can use `CArg` as template class. Else you can add more arguments to the constructor, but it would mean not decoration can be optional. I would have written the simple version of code and let optimiser module do the work.

Comment: You could try something like what std::'s streaming classes give you for altering their operators with manipulators (like `cout << hex << MyVar`, to print MyVar in hex instead of decimal).  I'm not sure what kind of syntax I would choose for a `+` manipulator, but it might be worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

I would aim to support something like this:

```
poly += miter(10).limit(3)
```

That is:

```
class modifier
{
public:
    virtual polygon& add(polygon&) const = 0;
};

class miter : public modifier
{
public:
    miter(int width);
    miter& limit(int ml);

    virtual polygon& add(polygon&) const override;
};

polygon& operator +=(polygon& poly, const modifier& mod)
{
    return mod.add(poly);
}
```

If you want to apply the same operation to several polygons,  you can do this:

```
miter mod(10);
mod.limit(3);
polyA += mod;
polyB += mod;
polyC += mod;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind for option 2. 
If I want to perform the operation multiple times, e.g. on multiple polys, I have to respecify the parameters over and over.

Comment: @AdiShavit: If you want to perform the same operation multiple times, you can!  I've added a snippet at the bottom of my answer showing how.

Comment: Of course. What I meant was: `polyA += 10; polyB += 3;...` where this would mean  `polyA += miter(10).limit(3); polyB += miter(3).limit(3); ...`. The latter is obviously more verbose. If the `+=` was a labmda-like object and the limit was the capture, then the first snippet would be sufficient.

Comment: @AdiShavit: Now it sounds like you want global variables.  Which you can certainly use if you want to!

Comment: Not really. I want the operator overload *function* to behave like a lambda (which is actually an object) where the extra params are set e.g. as captured values. Basically, the overloading function would (1) accept multiple params (more than two); (2) these will be *bound* (as in `std::bind()`) to some values returning a binary overloading function, which would then (3) be called as a binary operator overloading function. This is all local with possibly run-time values.

Comment: So you basically want `auto mod = std::bind(miter, _1, 3); mod(polyA, 10); mod(polyB, 3);` but with infix notation instead of regular function call notation?  I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: Yes, that is the direct way of stating this. And since I don't know how to state that either I thought there may be other ways maybe via some namespace and template instantiation trick...

Answer (score 1):

I warn in advance that my solution is a bit hackish and uscaleable. But if the sole purpose is to reduce the verbosity of the expression for the user..  You can do something akin to the [following](http://ideone.com/KwB8J5):

```
template<class Space>
class numeric
{
  long double _val;
public:
  numeric (long double val) : _val(val) {}
  operator long double() { return _val; }
};

struct s_mither;
numeric<s_mither> operator ""_mtr(long double v) { return v; }

enum class end_token_t : char {};
constexpr end_token_t end_token{};

class entity
{
  struct op_params_t
  {
    long double _scalar;
    long double _mither;
    bool        _in_op;

  } op_params;

public:
  entity& operator+= (long double scalar)
  { op_params._in_op = true; op_params._scalar = scalar; return *this;}

  entity& operator+= (numeric<s_mither> mither)
  { op_params._in_op = true; op_params._mither = mither; return *this;}

  entity& operator, (long double scalar)
  { if(op_params._in_op) op_params._scalar = scalar; return *this;}

  entity& operator, (numeric<s_mither> mither)
  { if(op_params._in_op) op_params._mither = mither; return *this;}

  void    operator, (end_token_t)
  { op_params._in_op = false; }
};


int main() {
    entity e;

    e += 10.0, 1.0_mtr, end_token;
    e += 20._mtr, 5, end_token;

    return 0;
}
```

It's ugly, but has the benefit of having all parameters be optional.
Sadly I wasn't able to bypass the token.

A better solution will probably be to provide a start token which return a temporary "collector" object on the first comma. That way you can keep all the comma operator overloading outside of your actual entity class.

Comment: +1 for originality, but I can't say this improves readability which is really the main point here :-).
Even without the `end_token` I believe neoither the syntax nor the semantics are clear. The user will need to remember what happens in what order and that is too much of a burden I think.

Comment: @AdiShavit, I agree. That's why I faffed around with the custom literals. I wonder though if the notion of user added named operators is more of a step in the right direction. https://github.com/klmr/named-operator

Comment: @StoryTelller: Thought about that, but in my case the arithmetic and boolean operators are just what I need (and their precedence is already guaranteed to be correct). But, yeah, with the custom operator tricks it may be possible to add extra "pre-params".